# Form validation with js if one of the entries in the table rows is filled in, the other must also be filled in before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html

Here's an example of the form. Note: in each TR(Line) the user, when filling in an input, has to fill in the other input as well.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e){
      
      var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#tabcli1 tr");
      
      for(var x = 0; x < tr.length; x++){
         
         var inps = tr[x].querySelectorAll("input");
         
         for(var i = 0; i < inps.length; i++){
            if(inps[i].value.trim()) break;
         }

         if(i == inps.length){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Tem de preencher os dois campos das linhas que tem um valor!");
            break;
         }else{
           
         }
         
      }
   
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;" id="tabcli1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="float: right; width:  100%;">
  <button class="btn btn-raised btn-success ripple-effect" style="float: right;" >Gravar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

The way my code is running forces me to fill in at least one input on each line.

What I want is that if you fill in one of the inputs on the line, it forces you to fill in the other input on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with below code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e){
  
    var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#tabcli1 tr");
    var flag = false;
  
    for(var x = 0; x < tr.length; x++){
     
        var inps = tr[x].querySelectorAll("input");
        var selcts = tr[x].querySelectorAll("select");
     
        for(var i = 0; i < inps.length && i < selcts.length; i++){
            if((inps[i].value.trim() != '' && selcts[i].value.trim() == '') || (inps[i].value.trim() == '' && selcts[i].value.trim() != '')) {
                flag = true;
            }
    
        }
    }
    if(flag == true) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Tem de preencher os dois campos das linhas que tem um valor!");
        flag = false;
    }
}
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;" id="tabcli1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table__row">
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Quantidade"><input min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantid[]" ></td>
      <td class="table__content" data-heading="Tamanho"><select class="form-control" name="taman[]"><option></option><option value="S"> S</option><option value="M"> M</option><option value="L"> L</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="float: right; width:  100%;">
  <button class="btn btn-raised btn-success ripple-effect" style="float: right;" >Gravar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: that's what i intend.  But I want it to only force you to fill in the two fields on the same line, if one of them is filled. If none of the fields are filled, allow this line to be blank

Comment: Script is updated as your need. if your issue is resolved mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks. That's it